# DB precision padded with random numbers using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, oracle, precision, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` to run an insert SQL statement. The field I want to insert into is a `NUMBER`. The value is: `-0.11111111` of type `float`. However, after insertion into DB, the value I get is padded with random numbers `-0.1111111119389534`.

Note that when I use direct JDBC, the value is inserted as it is, without the padded numbers.

I use `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource` and `MapSqlParameterSource` for setting the parameters of the INSERT statement, both giving same results. The code looks like this:

```
BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(stat);
int n = jt.update(query, params);
```

where jt is an instant of `SimpleJdbcTemplate`.

The DB is Oracle.

Thank you.

Comment: May I know which version of Spring JDBC in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java's `float` datatype, Spring JDBC behaves differently than direct JDBC.

Consider SQL statement `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (-0.11111111)` with `field` Oracle type `NUMBER` and -0.11111111 of type float.

With direct JDBC, it gives the value of `field` as it is, i.e. -0.11111111.

But with Spring JDBC (using `JdbcTemplate.update()`, it gives the value of `field` padded with numbers, i.e. -0.1111111119389534.

No such difference occurs for Java type `double`. The inserted value is not padded with numbers.

With Java datatype `BigDecimal`, the inserted value into DB will also be padded with numbers, i.e. -0.1111111099999999990428634077943570446223 and this is consistent for both direct JDBC and Spring JDBC.

The results for `float` is understandable, as Java states in its documentation that "(Float) data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency." So eventhough the behaviour is different in direct JDBC and Spring JDBC, we can't say it's wrong.

For `BigDecimal`, read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29

Comment: I asked another question about the BigDecimal problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074735/bigdecimal-variable-padded-with-random-numbers-in-jdbc-insert