# BigDecimal variable padded with random numbers in JDBC Insert

Tags: java, oracle, precision, bigdecimal

Consider SQL statement `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (-0.11111111)` with `field` Oracle type NUMBER.

When the value to be inserted is of type float or double, you get the exact value in `field`, i.e. -0.11111111.

But when the value to be inserted is of type `BigDecimal`, you get the value padded with random numbers, i.e. 0.1111111099999999990428634077943570446223.

Why?

Java states that "`BigDecimal` is an immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers."

The code is:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO pat_statistics (file_key,test_number,rqw)"
    + " VALUES (3778, 100, " + new BigDecimal(-0.11111111) + ")";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
int n = st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The DB is Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a literal value you should always use the BigDecimal constructor taking a string argument. See the [documentation of the BigDecimal(double) constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) for details.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the BigDecimal from a `double` so it will reflect exactly the value of the `double`, and as you probably know the trailing digits of a float are more ore less random.

I assume you see this in the database because the JDBC driver thinks: Hey I am getting a `BigDecimal`. I can use all the digits I can master.

When you use `float` or `double` the JDBC driver knows I can't realy use all the digits and ignores what comes after that threshold.

If you need the additional precision of `BigDecimal`, create it from a `String` or calculate it from `Integer`s.

#### a correction

The handling is not done by the JDBC driver, but by the various `toString` conversions, since you are assembling your SQL String.

BTW: you really should use bind variables for this.

Comment: Thanks Jens. Just a little correction: the BigDecimal is created from double, not float.